# OpenERP own Prefix Sequence

Tags: python, xml, odoo

how to create sequence number in openerp 7 like below

its already supported for

```
<field name="prefix">STJ/%(year)s/</field>
```

but i need to add my own record & create like this

```
<field name="prefix">%(employer_no)s/</field>
```

employer_no mention in my form

please refer my code in here 
https://github.com/priyankahdp/openerp/blob/openerp/

Comment: You can not put employer_no like this in prefix, its only support month year minutes hours etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your only chance for injecting custom variables into sequence interpolation is to override the [`interpolation_dict` method of `ir.sequence`](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~openerp/openobject-server/7.0/view/head:/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_sequence.py#L179)